# Getting variable of Public Property from external script

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I'm wondering how to get a Public Property from an external script. The test code is below and and it seems to display an empty variable for `tValue` using this method.

Is there something I'm not doing here?

```
'External Code
Set nObj = New Test
Response.Write(nObj.tValue)

'The Class
Class Test
    Public Test1

    Public Property Get tValue
        tValue = Test1
    End Property

    Sub Loadit
        Test1="123"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your constructor is incorrect. The default name of the constructor of a class in classic ASP is `Class_Initialize`. Based on that, your code should be:

```
'External Code
Set nObj = New Test
Response.Write("tValue = " & nObj.tValue)

'The Class
Class Test
    Private Test1

    Public Property Get tValue
        tValue = Test1
    End Property

    Public Sub Class_Initialize
        Test1 = "123a"
    End Sub 
End Class
```

Or if you wish to keep the code of your class as-is, you should change your external code to:

```
'External Code
Set nObj = New Test
nObj.Loadit
Response.Write(nObj.tValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, Its because it wasn't calling the Sub first.

This fixed it.

```
 'External Code
 Set nObj = New Test

 Call nObj.Loadit

 Response.Write(nObj.tValue)
```